# CSV file not creating correctly

Tags: php, csv

I am creating a **CSV** file using array.But created file is not correctly creating.

**PHP CODE**

```
$sss=mysql_query("SELECT DATE(pdate),COUNT(*) AS mycount FROM qchat_sessions WHERE MONTH(pdate)='09' GROUP BY DATE(pdate)");
$array=array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sss)){
$array[] =  array ($rows[0], $rows[1]); 

}
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($array as $row) {
fputcsv($fp, $row);

}
fclose($fp);
```

Its create the file  [CSV](http://livechathero.com/img/1.csv) with data and HTML of the page. but i want only this

**2013-09-26  1
2013-09-27  2
2013-09-28  2**

in CSV file. Why CSV generating with HTML ?

Thanks

Comment: Then don't generate the html: exit after the `fclose($fp);`

Comment: Thanks it works..but in place of date it is shwoing ######  and how can i add headings in it?

Comment: @user2802100 i think you are not more familiar with EXCEL. try to increase the tab head width in MS excel. problem will be solve..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy thanks..so  how i can have tabs already formatted and how to add headings to columns?

Comment: @user2802100 sorry for this but you wants to do it in PHP or in Excel ?

Comment: You can't have the Excel column widths already set with a CSV file, Excel don't swing that way.... you either need to create a real Excel file, which does support formatting such as column widths, or use html (and risk the "file format doesn't match extension" warning)

Comment: if you want to add CSV head in PHP then simply do this. before the array generate.
   
$csv = '"Column 1","Column 2"' . "\n";

Comment: confused..can u plz edit that above @PuzzledBoy

Comment: `$array=array(); $array[] = array('Column1', 'Column2')` That's how you set the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sss=mysql_query("SELECT DATE(pdate),COUNT(*) AS mycount FROM qchat_sessions WHERE MONTH(pdate)='09' GROUP BY DATE(pdate)");
    $array=array(); 
    $array[] = array('Column1', 'Column2');
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sss)){
    $array[] =  array ($rows[0], $rows[1]); 

    }
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($array as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);

    }
    fclose($fp); 
    exit;
```